# Manage Azure Personal and Work subscription with single login (Work-account) and same e-mailaddress

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've two Azure subscriptions: one from MAPS, on my personal account, for dev/test. And another one (for production) on my Work account.

Now i've to logout/login or switch browser (in-private-modus) to manage both subscriptions.
My personal account and work account have exactly the same e-mailaddress.

When I try to add a gueast-user (to grant this user access as co-admin), this isn't possible, because 'User name already exists in this directory'

So my question is: how can I add my work-account as co-admin to my personal subscription, while both accounts have the same e-mailaddress?

Comment: If you want to keep two accounts with the same email address and the two Azure subscriptions, there is no way to make you want. Because the username is the email address in the Azure.